# Install Esper in Eclipse

Tags: java, esper

I'm struggling to install Esper in Eclipse. I'm not good at technical issues, so please I need all details to do so.

In fact, I added all jar files of esper-5.4.0.zip in Java **build** path of my project. I have got the following error messages:

```
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (com.espertech.esper.util.ObjectInputStreamWithTCCL).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
Exception in thread "main" com.espertech.esper.client.EPStatementException: Failed to resolve event type: Event type or class named 'Deposit' was not found [every A=Deposit]
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementLifecycleSvcImpl.compile(StatementLifecycleSvcImpl.java:1162)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementLifecycleSvcImpl.createStopped(StatementLifecycleSvcImpl.java:298)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementLifecycleSvcImpl.createStoppedAssignName(StatementLifecycleSvcImpl.java:202)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.StatementLifecycleSvcImpl.createAndStart(StatementLifecycleSvcImpl.java:156)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorImpl.createPatternStmt(EPAdministratorImpl.java:108)
    at com.espertech.esper.core.service.EPAdministratorImpl.createPattern(EPAdministratorImpl.java:58)
    at test.CEP_start.main(CEP_start.java:39)
```

Comment: Could you tell us where did you get the project zip and the other zip files you've used? If we are to help, we need to know this.

Comment: Hi, thanks. I got the project zip from this link: http://www.espertech.com/esper/download.php

Comment: Regarding Deposit, I have the following class:


class Deposit{
 private float amount;
 private String customerID;
 public String getCustomerID(){
  return customerID;
 }
 public void setCustomerID(String customerID){
  this.customerID=customerID;
 }
 public float getAmount(){
  return amount;
 }
 public void setAmount(float amount){
  this.amount=amount;
 }
 
}

Answer (score 0):

When you create a statement like `select * from Deposit` that requires that you tell the engine what a "Deposit" is. That is done by adding an event type.

The documentation and tutorials have plenty of introductory examples or you could review the examples that comes with the Esper download.